# How can use an integer to specify and print out an item in array at the same time?

Tags: python, arrays

I tried to get the user to input a 3 digit item_number that will correspond with a specific item and a small description, so that it would print one of the 10 items out without having to write out each if-statements, but every time I tried `int(input())` it says int is not scriptable and when I use str it says that I need to use int or slice.

I am a novice coder and would like some help.

This is my code:

```py
chosen = int(input("Which item are you bidding on?"))
chosen_again = (chosen[2])
bidding = [item_number_list[chosen_again],description_list[chosen_again]]
print(','.join(bidding))
```

Examples of the item_numbers and descriptions:

```py
item_number_list = [101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110]
description_list = ["3G Telecoms Licenses",
"UK Gold Reserves",
"Boeing C-17 Globemaster III",
"Les Femmes d'Alger by Pablo Picasso",
"Giacometti’s Pointing Man",
"Oppenheimer Blue",
"1962-63 Ferrari 250 GTO Berlinetta",
"The Clark Sickle-Leaf Carpet",
"The Codex Leicester by Leonardo da Vinci",
"Patek Philippe Wristwatch"]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `chosen_again = (chosen[2])`? You can't do indexing on an integer.

Comment: If you just get rid of `chosen_again` and use `chosen` in your third line, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Zip to bind both the lists

```
    item_number_list = [101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110]

    description_list = ["3G Telecoms Licenses",
    "UK Gold Reserves",
    "Boeing C-17 Globemaster III",
    "Les Femmes d'Alger by Pablo Picasso",
    "Giacometti’s Pointing Man",
    "Oppenheimer Blue",
    "1962-63 Ferrari 250 GTO Berlinetta",
    "The Clark Sickle-Leaf Carpet",
    "The Codex Leicester by Leonardo da Vinci",
    "Patek Philippe Wristwatch"]
    
    print(list(zip(item_number_list,description_list)))
```

Output:

```
[(101, '3G Telecoms Licenses'), (102, 'UK Gold Reserves'), (103, 'Boeing C-17 Globemaster III'), (104, "Les Femmes d'Alger by 
Pablo Picasso"), (105, 'Giacometti’s Pointing Man'), (106, 'Oppenheimer Blue'), (107, '1962-63 Ferrari 250 GTO Berlinetta'), (
108, 'The Clark Sickle-Leaf Carpet'), (109, 'The Codex Leicester by Leonardo da Vinci'), (110, 'Patek Philippe Wristwatch')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using int input as an index, you can do something like this to make it work:

```
chosen_index = item_number_list.index(chosen)
bidding = [item_number_list[chosen_index],description_list[chosen_index]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can't access digits of an `int` like an array**

---

In the second line of your code you write:

`chosen_again = (chosen[2])`

This is where the error occurs because you are trying to access a digit of an `int` like an array. This will not work. But there are various fixes you can do, for example because you just want the number without 100 you can do this:

`chosen_again = chosen % 100`

Which will give you the number mod 100. Or perhaps:

`chosen_again = chosen - 100`

There are many fixes.

Comment: I cant believe I didn't think of that last one... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from the question, you want some sort of mapping from a user input to the description string. If that's the case, i'd suggest using a dictionary object, which can be constructed with:

`mapping_table = {idx: name for (idx, name) in zip(item_number_list, description_list)}`

Now, you can can call the dictionary items straight with the input as such:

```
chosen = int(input("Which item are you bidding on?"))
bidding = [str(chosen), mapping_table[chosen]]
print(', '.join(bidding))
```

With an input of `101`, you'd get:

`101, 3G Telecoms Licenses`

A much cleaner way (imo) would be to have an underlying mapping table, whether it'd be in the form of a .csv or .db, which can be read in and looked up whenever required. This way, any changes to the mappings will be done externally and the source code does not need to be changed.

Comment: OMG lifesaver thanks so much I never knew of this!

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this would be using arrays method [index](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index)

The solution would be something like this

```
item_number_list = [101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110]
description_list = ["3G Telecoms Licenses",
"UK Gold Reserves",
"Boeing C-17 Globemaster III",
"Les Femmes d'Alger by Pablo Picasso",
"Giacometti’s Pointing Man",
"Oppenheimer Blue",
"1962-63 Ferrari 250 GTO Berlinetta",
"The Clark Sickle-Leaf Carpet",
"The Codex Leicester by Leonardo da Vinci",
"Patek Philippe Wristwatch"]

user_input = int(input("Which item are you bidding on?"))
try:
    print(description_list[item_number_list.index(user_input)])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Correct Output:

```
Which item are you bidding on?110
Patek Philippe Wristwatch
```

Output(That Handles Invalid Numbers):

```
Which item are you bidding on?111
111 is not in list
```